# Pass on URL parameters to an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to pass on URL parameters from my URL to an iframe. When trying to get the id from iframe using document.getelementid, it returns a null/undefined value.

The main site is hosted on domain A, but the iframe is hosted on domain B.

Any insight?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your attempt there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.